# Broken Styles when using XamlReader to parse and insert a FlowDocument into a RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I am converting Html to Xaml(`FlowDocument` to be exact) and use `XamlReader` to parse the newly created `FlowDocument`. I then insert my new `FlowDocument` into the `RichTextBox`, but none of my Application level Styles get applied to the `FLowDocument` elements such as the `Hyperlink`s.
An example of one of my styles:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkBlue" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
</Style>
```

Can anyone help me figure this one out?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out... I used a FlowDocumentScrollViewer instead of the RichTextBox to view my FLowDocument.  For some reason the styles don't get applied when the container is a RichTextBox...